# TypeError in AutoComplete ajax in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, autocomplete

I have the following error in jquery.autocomplete.min.js

**TypeError: d is undefined**

my home.jsp file

```
    <head>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/core/jquery.1.10.2.min.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/core/jquery.autocomplete.min.js" />"></script>

      <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />"   rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
     <body>
          <div class="container">
          <div class="vendor_input">
               <input type="text" id="vendorname" path="vendorname" />
              <input type="button" value="GO" />
         </div>
       </div>

     </body>
   </html>
   <script type ="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() 
      {  

          jQuery('#vendorname').autocomplete({
                serviceUrl:         '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getDetails',
          paramName: "vendorName",
          delimiter: ",",
          transformResult: function(response) 
          {
             //alert(response);
            return
           {        
               suggestions: jQuery.map(jQuery.parseJSON(response), function(item) 
             {
                return {value: item.vendorname, data: item.vendorid};
             })
           };
         }
    });


    });

    </script>
```

the function getDetails() in homeController.java

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/getDetails",method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = "Accept=application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public @ResponseBody ArrayList<vendor> getTags(@RequestParam String vendorName) 
{
    System.out.println("enter into controller");
    ArrayList<vendor> data = new ArrayList<vendor>();
    data.add(new vendor(1, "ruby"));
    data.add(new vendor(2, "rails"));
    data.add(new vendor(3, "c / c++"));
    data.add(new vendor(4, ".net"));
    data.add(new vendor(5, "python"));
    data.add(new vendor(6, "java"));
    data.add(new vendor(7, "javascript"));
    data.add(new vendor(8, "jscript"));
    ArrayList<vendor> result = new ArrayList<vendor>();
    for (vendor tag : data) {
        if (tag.vendorname.contains(vendorName)) {
            result.add(tag);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Ajax is working fine. While displaying the suggestion I have TypeError: d is undefined error in my console. Is it any jquery version problem. Please help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the unminified version of the library and see if you get a better error message.

Comment: I did but it is a same TypeError: d is undefined in jquery.autocomplete.min.js

Comment: Sounds like that is still the min version....Are the suggestions being mapped correctly?

Comment: yes it was correcly mapped. The response text is correct.

Answer (score 0):

not sure but you are putting all your script outside of the closing `</html>`:

```
 </html>
 <script type ="text/javascript">
```

you can put it inside of closing `</body>`.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.